# inner join instead of inner selection does not work well

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following query which is working(and two table called topic and topic_dataitem_relation)  :

```
SELECT * FROM omid.topic as t
WHERE t.ID NOT IN (
SELECT tdr.TopicID FROM omid.topic_dataitem_relation As tdr
WHERE tdr.DataitemID = 37
);
```

but I want when I use joining I can not achieve the same result:

```
SELECT distinct * 
FROM omid.topic as t
left join  omid.topic_dataitem_relation As tdr
ON t.ID != tdr.TopicID
WHERE tdr.DataitemID = 37;
```

Can anyone help me if it is possible to do that with joining ?(thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

JOIN is also a condition, so to apply other conditions, must be use AND whereas, 
your query will be :

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM omid.topic as t
    JOIN omid.topic_dataitem_relation As tdr
    ON t.ID != tdr.TopicID
    AND tdr.DataitemID = 37; /* Your WHERE BECOME AND */
    /* AND condition2 = value 2*/
    /* AND ..... */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but still the same problem.It does not work!

Comment: "DISTINCT *" is just about the daftest thing you can put in an sql query

Comment: we don't need it, I paste it unconsciously

Comment: Even without distinct does not return the correct result

Comment: and this : 

SELECT * 
    FROM omid.topic as t
    JOIN omid.topic_dataitem_relation As tdr
    ON t.ID != tdr.TopicID
    AND tdr.DataitemID <> 37;

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, but still no result